# How to fix mongodb array cannot be displayed, private by yii2 BaseActiveRecord?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, yii2

I tried to create table to display data value from the database document, but somehow it cannot be displayed.

After several trouble solving, I found that my array was private by baseactiverecord even though I didn't use baseactiverecord on my models

here my database User document

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c3da89284274926934b86a3"),
    "id" : 1,
    "username" : "admin",
    "password" : "admin",
    "role" : 20
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c3da90384274926934b86b1"),
    "id" : 2,
    "username" : "admin2",
    "password" : "admin2",
    "role" : 20
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c3da90384274926934b86b3"),
    "id" : 3,
    "username" : "admin3",
    "password" : "admin3",
    "role" : 20
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c3da90384274926934b86b5"),
    "id" : 4,
    "username" : "user",
    "password" : "user",
    "role" : 10
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c3da90384274926934b86b7"),
    "id" : 5,
    "username" : "user2",
    "password" : "user2",
    "role" : 10
}
```

Models/User

```
<?php 
namespace home\models; 

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\mongodb\Database;
use yii\mongodb\Collection;
use yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord;
use yii\mongodb\Query;

class User extends ActiveRecord {
  public $_id;
  public $id;
  public $username;
  public $password;
  public $role;

    public static function collectionName()
    { return 'User'; }

    public function attributes()
    {
      return [
         '_id',
         'id',
         'username',
         'password',
         'role',        
      ];
    }


}
?>
```

Controller/home

```
<?php
namespace home\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\base\InvalidArgumentException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use home\models\ContactForm;    
use home\models\LoginForm;   
use home\models\SignupForm;        
use home\models\User; 


class HomeController extends Controller{

    public $layout = 'home';
    public function actionAbout()
    {
    $user = User::find()-> all();
    return $this->render('about', ['model' => $user]); 
    }

}
```

And this the result i got

```
Array
(
    [0] => home\models\User Object
        (
            [_id] => 
            [id] => 
            [username] => 
            [password] => 
            [role] => 
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5c3da89284274926934b86a3
                        )

                    [id] => 1
                    [username] => admin
                    [password] => admin
                    [role] => 20
                )

            [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5c3da89284274926934b86a3
                        )

                    [id] => 1
                    [username] => admin
                    [password] => admin
                    [role] => 20
                )

            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => home\models\User Object
        (
            [_id] => 
            [id] => 
            [username] => 
            [password] => 
            [role] => 
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5c3da90384274926934b86b1
                        )

                    [id] => 2
                    [username] => admin2
                    [password] => admin2
                    [role] => 20
                )

            [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5c3da90384274926934b86b1
                        )

                    [id] => 2
                    [username] => admin2
                    [password] => admin2
                    [role] => 20
                )

            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => home\models\User Object
        (
            [_id] => 
            [id] => 
            [username] => 
            [password] => 
            [role] => 
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5c3da90384274926934b86b3
                        )

                    [id] => 3
                    [username] => admin3
                    [password] => admin3
                    [role] => 20
                )

            [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5c3da90384274926934b86b3
                        )

                    [id] => 3
                    [username] => admin3
                    [password] => admin3
                    [role] => 20
                )

            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => home\models\User Object
        (
            [_id] => 
            [id] => 
            [username] => 
            [password] => 
            [role] => 
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5c3da90384274926934b86b5
                        )

                    [id] => 4
                    [username] => user
                    [password] => user
                    [role] => 10
                )

            [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5c3da90384274926934b86b5
                        )

                    [id] => 4
                    [username] => user
                    [password] => user
                    [role] => 10
                )

            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [4] => home\models\User Object
        (
            [_id] => 
            [id] => 
            [username] => 
            [password] => 
            [role] => 
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5c3da90384274926934b86b7
                        )

                    [id] => 5
                    [username] => user2
                    [password] => user2
                    [role] => 10
                )

            [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 5c3da90384274926934b86b7
                        )

                    [id] => 5
                    [username] => user2
                    [password] => user2
                    [role] => 10
                )

            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Can you tell me what step made me call BaseActiveRecord? And how to make the array visible?
Maybe just like this for every document

```
(
    [_id] => 5c3da90384274926934b86b3
    [id] => 3
    [username] => admin3
    [password] => admin3
    [role] => 20
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> [SOLVED]

```
public function actionAbout()
{
    $user = User::find()->asArray()-> all(); // need define as array
    return $this->render('about', ['model' => $user]); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! The key is  "asArray()". I don't know why there is no place mention this in yii2 document.